# How to debug error when loading a custom sqlite fts5 extension?

Tags: sqlite

Written a custom ranking function for the sqlite3 full text engine (fts5). The extension compiles but throws a "segmentation fault (core dumped)  sqlite3" error when attempting to load it with ".load /var/www/rankprice.so" . Unsure about the correctness of my extension code.

I have replaced my original ranking function with code from the docs. The extension loading code is also pretty much copied from the docs.

THere are 3 functions: 
    static void rankprice( //Actual extension function,
    fts5_api *fts5_api_from_db(sqlite3 *db) // Gets pointer to the fts5_api pointer 
    int sqlite3_extension_init // Loads the extension

The docs have not been updated on https://www.sqlite.org/fts5.html#extending_fts5 . In the function

```
fts5_api *fts5_api_from_db(sqlite3 *db){
    fts5_api *pRet = 0;
    sqlite3_stmt *pStmt = 0;
    if( SQLITE_OK==sqlite3_prepare(db, "SELECT fts5(?1)", -1, &pStmt, 0) ){
        sqlite3_bind_pointer(pStmt, (void*)&pRet, "fts5_api_ptr", NULL);
        sqlite3_step(pStmt);
    }
    sqlite3_finalize(pStmt);
    return pRet;
}
```

`sqlite3_bind_pointer` should have 5 arguments , the second argument should be an int, but I am unsure of its correct value.

Here is the complete code:

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <assert.h>
    #include "sqlite3ext.h"
    SQLITE_EXTENSION_INIT1

    /*
    ** Actual extension function, copied  from https://www.sqlite.org/fts5.html
    */
    static void rankprice(
        const Fts5ExtensionApi *pApi,
        Fts5Context *pFts,
        sqlite3_context *pCtx,
        int nVal,
        sqlite3_value **apVal
    ){
          int rc;
          int nToken;
          rc = pApi->xColumnSize(pFts, -1, &nToken);
          if( rc==SQLITE_OK ){
            sqlite3_result_int(pCtx, nToken);
          }else{
            sqlite3_result_error_code(pCtx, rc);
          }
    }

    /*
    ** Return a pointer to the fts5_api pointer for database connection db.
    ** If an error occurs, return NULL and leave an error in the database
    ** handle (accessible using sqlite3_errcode()/errmsg()).
    */
        fts5_api *fts5_api_from_db(sqlite3 *db){
            fts5_api *pRet = 0;
            sqlite3_stmt *pStmt = 0;
            if( SQLITE_OK==sqlite3_prepare(db, "SELECT fts5(?1)", -1, &pStmt, 0) ){
                sqlite3_bind_pointer(pStmt, 1,(void*)&pRet, "fts5_api_ptr", NULL);
                sqlite3_step(pStmt);
            }
            sqlite3_finalize(pStmt);
            return pRet;
        }

    /* Creates a SQL extension function. Tells sqlite which function to load as extension*/
    int sqlite3_extension_init(
        sqlite3 *db,
        char **pzErrMsg,
        const sqlite3_api_routines *pApi
    ){
        fts5_api *fpApi;
        fpApi = fts5_api_from_db(db);
        SQLITE_EXTENSION_INIT2(pApi);

        struct Builtin {
            const char *zFunc;                          /* Function name (nul-terminated) */
            void *pUserData;                            /* User-data pointer */
            fts5_extension_function xFunc;              /* Callback function */
            void (*xDestroy)(void*);                    /* Destructor function */
        } aBuiltin [] = {
                { "rankingMe", 0, rankprice, 0 },
        };
        int rc = SQLITE_OK;
        rc = fpApi->xCreateFunction(fpApi,
            aBuiltin[0].zFunc,
            aBuiltin[0].pUserData,
            aBuiltin[0].xFunc,
            aBuiltin[0].xDestroy
        );
        return rc;
    }
```

Compiled using 
`gcc -shared -fPIC -g /var/www/rankprice.c -o /var/www/rankprice.so`

Exact error message:

```
SQLite version 3.28.0 2019-04-16 19:49:53
Connected to a transient in-memory database.
sqlite> .load /var/www/rankprice.so
[2]    52632 segmentation fault (core dumped)  sqlite3
```

Links:
https://www.sqlite.org/fts5.html
https://github.com/sqlite/sqlite/blob/ff119f04b42a7ad3a16c306446af7e301d34026a/ext/fts5/fts5_aux.c

Comment: Should be `sqlite3_rankprice_init` not `sqlite3_extension_init`. If that doesn't help... time to break out the debugger.

Comment: Also, `SQLITE_EXTENSION_INIT2()` should be the first thing in the init function before any other sqlite function calls.

Comment: Yay! it loads now. Thanks a lot shawn.